# Calculating memory size from address and word size?

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

I'm currently studying for my computer architecture exam and I found this question online

> A digital computer has a memory unit with 26 bits per word. The
> instruction set consists of 756 different operations. All instructions
> have an operation code part (opcode) and an address part (allowing for
> only one address). Each instruction is stored in one word of memory.
>
> 1-How many bits are needed for the opcode? **10 bits**
>
> 2- How many bits are left for the address part of the instruction?
> **16 bits**
>
> 3- What is the maximum allowable size for memory? **65536 bits**
>
> 4- What is the largest unsigned binary number that can be
> accommodated in one word of memory? **67108864**

I understand why 1 and 2 are correct but I didn't understand 3 and 4

Shouldn't question 3 be **(2^16) x 26 bits**?

And shouldn't question 4 be **(2^26)- 1**?

Comment: That's the most generic meaningless title ever, it tells future readers nothing about what kinds of things the question is about, not even that it's about answers to quiz questions.  these *what*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part 4, you're calculating the largest *immediate* that can be part of an instruction word.
But the question asked about using the whole 26-bit word for a number, as data.   (Also, you did `2^15`, so the largest signed 16-bit integer, but the question asked for unsigned where all `n` bits have positive place-value).

For part 3, yes your answer looks correct.  Assuming there is no indirect addressing (which would let you use 26-bit addresses), then the usable memory size = the amount an instruction can address. So 2^16 = 65536 words.  Are you sure the given answer really meant 65536 bits, not words?

Comment: sorry it was a typo but can you please explain question 3 and 4 again? Also in question 3 you said my answer is correct but why did you say So 2^16 = 65536 words? My answer was 2^16 * 26 which is 1703936 words

Comment: @seen20: No, 1703936 **words** would be wrong, but that's not what you said in your question. You calculated 2^16 = 65536 words * 26 bits/word which is 1703936 **bits**, which is correct under those assumptions.  2^16 = 64K = 65536 is a number that comes up fairly often; 16-bit widths for things are not rare.

Comment: @seen20: If I wanted to say more about either question 3 or 4 I would have; if you want the explanation again, read my answer again, and think about why I said what I did.  If there's some specific aspect of it you didn't understand, be specific.

Comment: To get things straight q3 is 1703936 bits because 2^16 addresses can hold 26 bits right? And q4 shouldn't we start from 0 so the answer is (2^26)-1 am i right or wrong?

Comment: @seen20: You mean *each* of the 2^16 addresses can hold 26 bits?  Yes, assuming the memory is word-addressable.  (But since it's not specified, you get to choose the design for that part of the ISA, I guess.  Another possibility is a "byte" addressable machine with 13-bit bytes, so aligned words are only found at even addresses.  e.g. that's why a standard 32-bit machine like MIPS32 or Pentium can only address 4GiB of memory, not 4G * 4-byte words.  But if you're aiming for the largest possible memory, you wouldn't choose that.)

Comment: @seen20: q4: correct, 2^26 - 1 = 67108863.  So good point, the given answer for q4 is wrong.  The max representable value for some number of bits can never be even, when using a standard binary place-value encoding.

Comment: to wrap things up  q3 is 1703936 bits because each address can hold 26 bit and q4 is 67108863 because we start from 0 right? Also I'm not that good at this subject at q4 all i know is that we have to do (2^26)-1 but i have no idea why did we do that, iknow you answered it but can you explain it again please? Also can you explain q3 again? because I'm maybe understanding everything wrong,  I'm sorry if had bothered you but my exams are near and I have to understand

Comment: @seen20: yes for q3.  Yes, the number of unique values for n bits is `2^n`, and since we always start at 0 when using the normal binary place values (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number#Representation), the largest number is `2^n -1`.  For exactly the same reason that 4 decimal digits let you represent numbers up to 9999 = 10^4 - 1, with the largest number when each digit has its maximum place-value.  (9 for base 10, 1 for base 2)